# How to use @Where in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to implement a soft delete for my entities.
So I create this annoations:

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE ExternalReference SET deleted=true, deletedAt=now() WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
public class ExternalReference {
...
}
```

But Hibernate create this SQL Statement:

```
SELECT e1_0.id
     FROM external_reference e1_0
     WHERE e1_0.external_system=?
       AND e1_0.external_class=?
       AND e1_0.external_id=?
       AND (external_reference.deleted = 0)
```

In the last line you can see, hibernate insert the `external_reference.deleted = 0`, but with a wrong table name, right here were `e1_0.deleted = 0`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you mean it is wrong? external_reference is the correct name of your table.

Comment: No it is not. Hibernate make an alias e1_0, so the table name don't exists anymore.

Comment: If it cause an exception then I would say it is a bug. Did it work fine in Spring Boot 2?

Comment: I don't know, it's a new project

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the version of Hibernate you are using. I have just tested it with current version of Spring Boot Starter 3.0.5 (Hibernate 6.1.7 Final) Looks good:

```
Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.deleted,c1_0.email,c1_0.name from customer c1_0 
where c1_0.id=? and (c1_0.deleted = false)
```

For entity annotated as follows:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;

@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE Customer SET deleted=true WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
public class Customer {
// ...
}
```